Are boolean operations on shapes possible in MetaPost/MetaFun?
I am currently facing a, probably, simple problem. Problem which I couldn't find any satisfying solution.
For this example, let's say that I have a simple square and that I what to "remove" a circle in this square. The only way I know and could find with some google-fu is to unfill the circle:
  path c,s;
  s = unitsquare scaled 5cm;
  c = fullcircle scaled 2.5cm ;

  filldraw s withcolor lightgray ;
  unfill c shifted center s ;

As you might imagine, this piece of code is working well.

Well... in only one context: with a white background. If you have any colored blackground, unfill will not work as you might expected.

Indeed, what we might expect here, when "unfilling" a shape, is not to make that part of shape white but transparent.

Obviously, this is a simple case and I can just make the circle red (which I did in that last figure) but there are some cases where it is way harder to do it properly.
And this is where I wondered: is there a way to perform all boolean operations on shapes, easily done by vector graphics editors, such as union, intersection, and more in MetaPost/MetaFun?

Welcome! Are you able to complete the code snippet so we can copy-paste and compile it?

Here is a MetaFun way (added at some point in 2023) that might not be exactly what you look for, but something to build from perhaps (if you need general union or intersections, you probably need something rather complex):
You can use && that joins paths with a moveto. Reversing the inner path is necessary. Also, since we want to fill, we need to do close the path, which we do with && cycle.
\startMPpage[offset=1DK]

fill fullsquare scaled 10cm withcolor darkred ;

path c,s;
s = fullsquare scaled 5cm;
c = fullcircle scaled 2.5cm ;

filldraw (s && reverse c && cycle) withcolor lightgray ;
\stopMPpage

The result looks like this:


Thanks, this is already a big step forward and I think I can start working around with that. You did mention that general boolean operations on shapes would be complex. It's probably true. However, have you any idea where I should start?

I think the first thing to do is to determine all intersection points. You can find all times with p sortedintersectiontimes q or all points with p firstintersectionpath q. Once you have them, you need to start somewhere, loop through, and keep track. If the paths are "well behaved", it should not be impossible. Maybe there are better ways. (We were in fact discussing this in connection with last BachoTeX.)
